# verify ASCII file with file command by shell scrript

Tags: shell-script

With the file command I need to verify many files if they  ASCII or other format

Sometimes I get from file command:

```
  file1: ASCII English text
```

And sometimes I get different answer from file command

```
  file2: Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with very long lines
```

I am really not sure if there are other answers with different syntax

My question is:

I write the follwing ksh syntax to verify if file is a ASCII but I not sure if the

following syntax is the optimal syntax in order to verify ASCII format?

```
   [[ ` file  $some_file | grep –c ASCII ` = 1 ]] && print "you have ascii file for sure"
```

If someone have other suggestion to verify ASCII format for sure!, I will very glad to see that

Comment: ASCII? In the days of internet and Unicode? You must be joking.

Comment: You do realize that `file` is a heuristic guess and not a guarantee, right?  `yes | head -c $((2**20)) > blah; dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=1024 >> blah; file blah` says `blah: ASCII text` even though it's not.

Comment: yes I am understand but what I need to do if I want to make selection of files type , what the best thing to do? , any idea?

Answer (score 8):

```
if LC_ALL=C grep -q '[^[:print:][:space:]]' file; then
    echo "file contains non-ascii characters"
else
    echo "file contains ascii characters only"
fi
```

Comment: hi ephemient - please explain LC_ALL=C before the grep command , why?

Comment: `LC_ALL=C` forces `grep` to treat `[[:print:]]` as the "printable ASCII" character class.  Otherwise it means "printable <whatever your current locale is>", which may be non-ASCII.  For example, most Linux boxes are set up with UTF-8 locales, in which case `[[:print:]]` would match non-ASCII character sequences that are valid UTF-8 printable characters.

Comment: @jennifer: `name=value command` is the syntax for temporarily setting an environment variable, in this case `LC_ALL`, for a single command. Setting locale to `C` makes sure `[[:print:]]` only matches ASCII characters (and not accented characters from your language).

Comment: why I get "file contains non-ascii characters"  for /etc/hosts , as you know hosts file is ASCII file?

Comment: @jennifer: Fixed.  Probably included a tab or something like that; I forgot `[[:print:]]` is `[[:graph:] ]` not `[[:graph:][:space:]]`.

Comment: @ephemient hi , I check some files and I find that your code return "file contains non-ascii characters" but from file command I get:
Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with very long lines how to support this?

Comment: @ephemient hi again , from my previous remark from my point if I get "Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text" its also ASCII file , please if you can help me to update your code to support this

Comment: @jennifer: "Non-ISO extended-ASCII" is not any specific encoding at all.  I don't understand what you want to happen – it's clearly **not ASCII**.  Note that there are many different ISO-8859-* and non-ISO variants of extended ASCII character sets that `file` does not differentiate between, and any attempt to determine the character set is (at best) a guess.

Comment: @ephemient hi - but by VI its seems as simple text ordinary file with text and remarks what's the different

Comment: I am really not understand -:( why I get Non-ISO extended-ASCII on ordinary text file with simple text lines , maybe bug in the file command?

Comment: @jennifer: What does `perl -ne 'END {print join($", sort {$a <=> $b} keys %c), $/} undef @c{map ord, split //}'` say for this file?  Any values (other than 9, 10, or 13) below 32 or above 126?  What is the output of `locale`?

Comment: hi @ephemient the output:9 10 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 91 93 94 95 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 124 126 147 148

Comment: perl -ne 'END {print join($", sort {$a <=> $b} keys %c), $/} undef @c{map ord, split //}' file_test
9 10 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 91 93 94 95 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 124 126 147 148

Comment: @ephemient hi did you have some concussions about what I send from the output?

Comment: @jennifer: Yes, the 147 and 148 indicate that it's NOT ASCII.  What is your `locale`?

Comment: very strange this is configuration file with parameters and values , my target is to find all configuration files , and if they ascii files then I need to update those file by sed

Comment: So maybe I need to defied the Non-ISO extended-ASCII as configuration file also as ascii

Comment: @ephemient what's you think about the following: maybe I use the simple file command to verify if ASCII or Non-ISO extended-ASCII and then edit those files?

[[ ` file  $some_file | grep –c ASCII ` = 1 ]] || [[ ` file  $some_file | grep –c "Non-ISO extended-ASCII" ` = 1 ]]  && print "you have ascii file for sure"

Comment: @ephemient hi , did you agree with me about my solution?

Comment: @jennifer: You haven't answered.  What is your `locale`?  In any case, if you are trying to detect whether you should `sed` a file or not by a skim of its contents, I believe your approach is fundamentally flawed.  No, I do not agree at all.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand about the "locale" - did you mean if the machine is linux or solaris then my machine is alinux machine

Comment: about what you said that my approach is not very good , OK but what the other option did you have other idea?

Comment: as I said my target to edit files some files are binary and some files are configuration files and some of them are application - what I need to do is only to edit the configuration files (ASCII) did you have other suggestion?

Comment: What is the output of the `locale` command? § If the list of files were purely advisory, then a heuristic seems okay, but if you're actually going to be mangling them, it would be better to keep a registry of which files are to be affected.  Linux package managers like dpkg and rpm keep track of configuration files; you can tie into their system, or build your own.

Comment: the output:   LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=

Comment: and on my solaris machine:     locale
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: @jennifer: Take the `LC_ALL=C` part out and the command I gave will recognize those files on your Linux machine — but keep in mind that there will be unavoidable false positives, e.g. you can't tell the difference between ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15 encodings, nevermind foreign encodings like SJIS or GBK.

Comment: so the final syntax to verify if the file is ASCII is by : if  grep -q '[^[:print:][:space:]]' file; then... ( I am right ?)

Comment: @ephemient please your last opinion on my last remark -:)

Comment: if I want to summary this issue you say that (grep -q '[^[:print:][:space:]]' file) syntax is more safe then to use the file command to match the ASCI string , am I right?

Comment: @jennifer: `file` doesn't actually look at the whole file; it looks at the beginning, maybe looks at the end, and makes a guess.  This actually looks at the whole file, so I believe that this method is safer.  However, just by checking whether the contents of a file are consistent with a particular encoding (ASCII or otherwise) is still pretty meaningless on its own.

Comment: OK I will use your syntax (grep -q '[^[:print:][:space:]]' file) in my code I hope everything will be OK

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
if file -ib "$file" | grep -Eqs '^text/plain(;|$)'; then
    echo "It's text/plain."
fi
```

I don't know how common is `--mime-type`; if it's standard, use

```
if file -b --mime-type "$file" | grep -qs '^text/plain$'; then
```

---

Alternatively `grep -qs '^text/'` for any text type.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're parsing the output with code I'd suggest using the `-i` option on `file` so it outputs [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) types instead human-friendly strings. The MIME type output is more regular and that makes it a little easier to deal with in code.

As for the output types a look at [man file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) says that:

```
/usr/share/file/magic
    Default list of magic numbers

/usr/share/file/magic.mime
    Default list of magic numbers, used to output  mime types
    when the -i option is specified.
```

Take a look at those files for all the MIME types it can report to determine which types you'll care about when parsing the output from `file`. I suspect all you'll care is that the MIME type starts with `text/`.