# Useful alternative for file command

Tags: shell-script

I use the following shell syntax (from my previos questione, answered by - phemient) in order to verify if file is ASCII (text) or other

```
if LC_ALL=C grep -q '[^[:print:][:space:]]' file; then
   echo "file contains non-ascii characters"
   else
     echo "file contains ascii characters only"
fi
```

the problem is that I get "file contains non-ascii characters" (from the shell script syntax) even if the test_file is  ASCII file why?

I also test the file with file command and this is what I get

```
file test_file 
Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text" its also ASCII file
```

my question: how to change the shell syntax in order to support also "Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text" ?

so I will get the print "file contains ascii characters only" from the shell script

```
  remark the solution must be for Linux and solaris
```

THX

Comment: This is your second post on this topic ( [first here](http://superuser.com/questions/203695/verify-ascii-file-with-file-command-by-shell-scrript) ). Maybe you could say a few words about *why* you're trying to accomplish this. Possibly there is a different approach which will be more reliable.

Comment: the second post is about diffrent isshu ,

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're still working on the same underlying problem, right? I'm not claiming this is a duplicate, rather I'm suggesting that with more context we might be able to provide better help.

Comment: dear dmckee hi this post is continue the first post , the first post from my point is almost close but during my test I notice about little problem , please take a look on my first post many many remarks and if some one want to help its very difficult to understand what I want , therefore I ask the second post to clear this ishu

Answer (score -1):

Hi I would use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ `file -b $1` == "ASCII text" ]] ; then
   echo "file contains ascii characters only"
   else
     echo "file contains non-ascii characters"
fi
```

Looks like:

```
$ filetest.sh 1.txt  
file contains ascii characters only
$ filetest.sh PHOTOS/HPIM0532.jpg  
file contains non-ascii characters
```

Comment: what about Solaris -b option not defined in Solaris - what the same flag in Solaris? (i work on Linux and Solaris)

Comment: then put: 

if [[ `file $1 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/ //'` == "ASCII text" ]] ; then

Comment: @Warnaud hi sorry but I get also: Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with very long lines (I used the -b option) my target to define the file as ASCII also if I get the output  Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with very long lines

Comment: for example: file -b file_test
Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with very long lines

Comment: please advice according to my first original question how to change the shell syntax in order to support "Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text"

Comment: then you'll have to add another condition like:  


    #!/bin/bash
    if [[ `file -b $1` == "ASCII text" ]] ; then
       echo "file contains ascii characters only"
       elseif [[ `file -b $1` == "Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text" ]]; then
         echo "file contains extended-ascii characters"
       else
         echo "file contain non-ASCII characters"
    fi

Sorry for the horrible look I don't know how to format... looks like this on patesbin: http://pastebin.com/FuP05bsR

Comment: but I am very afraid if there are some other options that I not see? How to catch all ASCII options maybe there are some other output for ASCII

Comment: Hum, I see sorry, I got more into the original code.
What we need is a test that parse the output of the command 'file' to check if somewhere there's ASCII in it. I'm looking for it

Comment: I've found something promising and easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash

  Basically I would try if [[ `file $1` == *ASCII* ]]; then < and the normal code as the first code I posted >

Comment: so all the diff is the missing (-b) flag ?

Comment: Dennis did you cahnge somthing in the code?

Comment: Jennifer, as far as I understood you need to know which file are ASCII or non ASCII. Since the command 'file' can return several answer with an ASCII file, the last solution seems for me the easiest: it parses the return value of the command 'file your_parsed_file' and check if there is the ASCII string in it unfortunately due to the formatting ... we missed the stars surrounding the string ASCII.  
The code would looks like: if [[ `file $1` == ***ASCII*** ]]; then echo "ASCII"; else echo "non-ASCII"; fi

Comment: @Warnaud hi Your solution is logical but I am afraid if file return the following "Not ASCII file" the ASCII string exist but on the negative side how I know if this possibility realistic

Comment: maybe need to see file return list (all options in order to approve your code?)

Comment: Jennifer, it's your code that returns "Not ASCII file" the command file only returns as you mentioned "ASCII text" or "Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text" or similar but never "Not ASCII file". We can double check with the list of values returned by the command file (I don't find the list).